# How to connect foreign-key on 3 tables relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I dont know how to create a great title , iam sorry . so 
i have 3 table . **USER** , **SPECIAL_USER**, **EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER**

in USER i have data basic like

> **id ,name , address , email ,etc**

in SPECIAL_USER data

> **id , user_id , height , weight**

in EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER i have

> **id , special_user_id , name_school , skills , etc**

i have table **LIKE** on this table . i have problem how to call **EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER** based on id on **USER** . its have problem because my EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER is not have relation directly on USER table . 
its my controller , how to solve this

```
  public function PDF_profile(Request $request,$id){
   $users = User::findOrFail($id);
   $special_users= Special_Users::where('user_id',$id)->first();
   $EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER= EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER::where('Special_user_id',$id)->get();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.pdf_profile',
    [
    'EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER '=>$EDUCATION_SPECIAL_USER ,
    'users' => $users,
    'special_users'=> $special_users,



    ]);
    dd($r_kgb);
     //return $pdf->stream('Profile.pdf')->header('Content-Type','application/pdf'); 

}
```

this data is not out  because this wrong id , how i can solve this ?

Comment: all 3 one to one relationship ? it means user has one row data in other two tables ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "has-many-through" relationship:

```
// In your model User:
public function educationSpecialUsers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(EducationSpecialUser::class, SpecialUser::class);
}

// then use:
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$educationSpecialUsers = $user->educationSpecialUsers;
```

hope helpful.

Comment: I try this . Wait

Comment: i think i miss this perception . this id i mean on Special_User